# Selenium IDE 2.6 error-recording

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

I am running a test case in Selenium IDE and get the error:
[error] Element id=ui-id-31 not found.
This error comes when I click on an empty box where I want to type a value. 
I have tried different things like “verifyTextPresent“ and “waitForElementPresent“ but didn't work.

Does anyone have a clue how to manage this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are dealing with an HTML INPUT tag. The ID value is quite possibly being dynamically generated which means that it won't be the same in all cases. This is where automated testing gets a little more challenging and fun. A more sophisticated locator is needed.

My suggestion would be to look at the HTML source for the element to find the actual INPUT tag code. You will probably see something like:

```
<INPUT ID='some_value' NAME='some_other_value' CLASS='some_third_value'...>
```

There could be more attributes in the tag than ID, NAME, and CLASS but you get the picture. If this is the case, I suggest using an XPATH. XPATH is a more sophisticated element locator that Selenium IDE recognizes. XPATH locators begin with // and you supply it with the tag name and expected attributes. The tutorial is here and very valuable: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/.

In the above HTML INPUT example, a relative xpath would be

```
//INPUT[@NAME='some_other_value' and @CLASS='some_third_value']
```

You would replace the target value 'id=ui-id-31' with this. If you can put the INPUT tag HTML code in the comments for this thread I will be glad to evaluate it and suggest an XPATH.